# Error on running docker commands from jenkins pipleline

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I am trying to run a bash file inside a docker container in jenkins pipeline. Here is my bash file which compares two arrays and prints something if they are different:

```
// path/to/file/my-bash.sh
#!/bin/bash

array1="some array"
array2="some array"

result=$(echo ${array1[@]} ${array2[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u)

[ ! -z "$result" ] && echo "different arrays"
```

and here is the jenkins pipeline stage:

```
stage('Running the bash file') {
    sh """#!/bin/bash -l
        docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -p "${env.BUILD_TAG}" exec -T --user it php bash -l -c "cd /path/to/file && ./my-bash.sh" > result.txt
    """
}
```

Probably this line `result=$(echo ${array1[@]} ${array2[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u)` causes the problem because without it everything works fine. But I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Could you post the full log of your pipeline?